# what is the size of patch in pmvs?

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

i try to make pmvs in matlab with

> Yasutaka Furukawa et al.'s Paper "Accurate, Dense, and Robust Multi-View Stereopsis"

he say

> '**The extent of the rectangle is chosen so that the smallest axis-aligned square in R(p) containing its image projection is of size μ×μ pixels in size(μ is either 5 or 7 in all of our experiments).**'

i don't understand what it mean

i think i need some example about it 
can i get some example about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch extent is calculated in the following way:

1. Project patch p on to R(p) and get the patch in the image R(p), so now we have the pixels in the image R(p) that corresponds to the patch p - lets call this sub image Ip.
2. Take Ip and find the smallest square that enclose Ip - lets call it S(Ip). Axis aligned means that the square isn't oriented. See the difference between [Oriented bounding box](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect) and [Axis aligned bounding box](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect)
3. The size of S(Ip) needs to be μ X μ pixels.

Comment: thank you so much .
I'm sorry, but may I ask you one more question?

Comment: before we project patch p in 1. 
i make patch on reference image with 1 pixel space and reverse projection
it is right?
i'm sorry that my English may not be good enough to explain.

Comment: I didn't read the paper only the small section you were referring too so i don't know how exactly they do it but your idea sounds good